# Postgresql select distinct for every unique quarter

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, distinct, where-clause

I have a query

```
select * from table_name where sales=0
```

from which i got the following data

[image]

Now, **for every quarter** I want to **select distinct rows** so that final data will be like this

[image]

I am **able to get data for individual quarter** with

```
select distinct quarter, id from some_view where quarter='2020-Q2'
```

but I am unable to get a single query which can accommodate all quarters data.

please suggest how to proceed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might be oversimplifying this... But you do seem to want:

```
select distinct quarter, id from some_view where sales = 0
```

This gives you all distinct querter/id tuples, out of rows that satisfy the `where` clause.